# accessing a resource on amazon amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-amplify

I seem to be stuck on something very simple, I have a website hosted on amazon amplify (with a domain name attached to it)

I have a resource linked to it named "service"

I have set up that resource in the api gateway to proxy to an external address. I have deployed it and tested it and it works!

At the moment the endpoint just points to an an online echo service
the end point is here

https://igvfxr22m9.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/staging/service

if you add some random stuff to the end it will reflect in the response from the echo service,

for example https://igvfxr22m9.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/staging/service/test?value=7

will return "method":"GET","url":"https://enaktwozixqwc4h.m.pipedream.net/service/test?value=7","client_ip":"3.9.94.135","query":{"value":"7"}}

so that all works

If im looking at my amazon amplify control panel this resource "service" is listed under its resources. But now when i try to access that resource via its domain name it doesnt work. Ive tried https://xxxxxxx.com/service, https://xxxxxxx.com/staging/service and some other combinations. Note that there is no authentication on the resource.

How do I invoke my resource via die domain name of my amazon amplify website?

Answer (score 0):

So I have not yet figured out how to specifically achieve reverse proxying using amplify and the API gateway together, I did however figure out that you can set up a simple URL rewrite to a different domain in amplify directly, It's a lot less flexible than the API gateway but it serves my current purposes.